# Submit button doesn't call php script

Tags: php

While trying to create an Admin only comment editing system there seems to be an error while calling the "Edit" function

The function:

```html
function editComment($conn) {
 if (isset($_POST['submitComment'])) {
  $cid = $_POST['cid'];
  $uname = $_POST['uname'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];


  $sql = "UPDATE comments SET message='$message' WHERE cid='$cid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  header("Location:index.php");
  exit;
 } 

}
```

The php that should call the function:

```html
<?php

$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


echo "<form class='commentSection' method='POST' action='".editComment($conn)."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$cid."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='uname' value='".$uname."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$date."'>
 <textarea name='message'>".$message."</textarea><br>
 <button type='submit' name='editComment'>Edit!</button>
 </form>";
  ?>
```

Running the coder results in the edit page reloading but nothing adding into the database, and looking into the network tab on chrome I can't find any request towards the other php file with the function.

Live on github: https://github.com/TheWalkingM3m3/Test-Site

Comment: provide the result array

Comment: array(4) { ["cid"]=> string(1) "2" ["uname"]=> string(14) "TheWalkingM3m3" ["date"]=> string(19) "2017-07-16 20:50:08" ["message"]=> string(64) "Line break test, Is there a line break??? and another one!"

Comment: provide the full result array in your question.

Comment: That's what I did right? screenshot if you want, http://prntscr.com/fxj8w1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use var_dump($row); to debug the output of variable

You have mainly 2 types of error in this code :

it will display Notice: **Array to string conversion** in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\comments.inc.php on line 27 :

**You cannot echo a Array only string can be echo that's why Array to String conversion error**

Notice: **Undefined variable**: uname in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\comments.inc.php on line 28:

**In this if ($uname == 'TheWalkingM3m3') { - is checked and $uname variable is not set , Probably your above if(isset($_Session..) condition is skipped  , So , i recommend to declare $uname = ''; outside while loop. **

Comment: Moving $uname = ''; outside of the loop fixed half of the errors, how would I go about fixing the fixing the array to string conversion, if I don't do it I get this error: 
>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Answer (score 0):

var_dump($row),check the result firstly

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why a significant part of your code is between double quotes, but maybe there is a reason and you didn't mention it.

However, I don't know why you put curly brackets around all your variable names. Maybe you should consider removing them, at least around $uname, since it's neither an array key or object property.

Maybe if you explained more what that code is supposed to achieve it would be easier to point out where you made mistakes.

Comment: The code should let only the set 'Admin' of the site edit comments left there, instead of letting everyone do it (what I had before and it worked fine.)

Comment: That doesn't explain why your code is between quotes, or why there are curly brackets around most variables in that part. My understanding is that excluding your PHP code from these quotes would do some good there.

Comment: Ah, my code is echoed to the main index.php file, this file is in the includes folder. Although after removing a pair of double quotes I fixed all of my errors exept a css error but I'll see what I can do about that.

Comment: I by that you mean that you echo some code on purpose so that it's echoed in the file which includes the first file, that's not how it works. Include appends the content of the included file right where you call include. You don't need to put the code between quotes and after an echo for it to end in your index file, in fact doing that makes your code to be interpreted as text. Is your problem fixed, now ?

Comment: Yes, all php and html errors are now fixed, thanks a lot for your advice on my code, ill try to change my coding habit and use less quotes!